# What subprocess can substitute pip.main install?

Tags: python, pip, subprocess, installation

I'm trying to run someone's program, and I keep getting stuck at the **pip.main install**.

Specifically, we have:

```
import os, pip, sys, argparse
try:
  pip.main(["install", "-r", "requirements.txt"])
except SystemExit as e:
  pass
```

I've already read **pip.main isn't supported**, and I want to use a **subprocess**, but I can't find docs or anything to explain how I'd convert this specific line into a subprocess.

How I write an equivalent subprocess?

Where do I find the docs that should have been able to teach me this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed? If you write `pip` in your terminal (the standard terminal.. Win or Linux, not python terminal) , what is the response? (it could also be `pip3`)

Comment: @niCkcAMel Yep! I have pip 19.1.1 on a MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Simple usage:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', '-r', 'requiremetns.txt'])
```

You will probably want to handle errors though.